# Sleeping during the day instead of sleeping at night

Tags: sleep, sleep-cycles

Is there any difference to ones health outcome if they wake up at night and go to sleep when the sun rises up?

To be more specific, what will happen to a person if the sleep cycle is reversed?

Comment: +1 - As a full-time night-worker in the past I always wondered what possible implications there were.

Comment: Do you mean [SWSD](https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/diseases/12146-shift-work-sleep-disorder)?

Comment: One outcome that I can think of would be Vitamin D deficiency, as the person would presumably be getting very little exposure to sunlight. This probably could be managed though with suplements, and/or artificial UV lights etc.

Comment: @JMP I don't think OP had a particular condition in mind but it seems like SWSD would make a good component to an answer.

Comment: Please do not answer or argue in comments. Comments are for clarifying answers/questions.